# Is it possible to neatly flatten a list of maps from values.yaml by selecting a key present in each map?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Suppose I have a `values.yaml` that contains the following arbitrary-length list of maps:

```
values.yaml
-----------
people:
  - name: "alice"
    age: 56
  - name: "bob"
    age: 42
```

One of the containers in my stack will need access to a list of just the names. (`NAMES="alice,bob"`)

So far, I have come up with the following solution:

```
templates/_helpers.tpl
----------------------
{{- define "list.listNames" -}}
{{ $listStarted := false }}
{{- range .Values.people }}
{{- if $listStarted }},{{- end }}{{ $listStarted = true }}{{ .name }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

```
templates/configmap.yaml
------------------------
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  NAMES: '{{- include "list.listNames" . }}'
```

This solution works, but it feels inelegant. Looking through the Helm documentation, it seems like this would be the perfect use case for [`pluck`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#pluck) in combination with `join`, but I haven't found a way to use `.Values.people` as an argument to that function.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I'm fairly sure what you have now is the best way.  I don't think there's a Helm/Sprig function to extract data from a list of maps (for all that structure is reasonably common in Kubernetes) and there's not a general-purpose functional `map` call; so there's no way to get a list of just the names, and then `join` them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `join` function.
I've two different solutions to utilize `join`:

**Solution 1**

I can't collect the names in a list. Therefore I use a dict and extract the keys later:

```
{{- define "list.listNames" -}}
{{- $map := dict }}
{{- range .Values.people }}
{{- $_ := set $map .name "" }}
{{- end }}
{{- keys $map | join "," }}
{{- end }}
```

This solution might [change the order](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#keys). Perhaps `sortAlpha` could fix this.

**Solution 2**

Because function must return a map, I need to add a key. Otherwise you can't convert to a dict by `fromYaml`:

```
templates/_helpers.tpl
----------------------
{{- define "list.listNames" -}}
items:
    {{- range .Values.people }}
    - {{ .name }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Then I convert to a dict object by `fromYaml` and join the list:

```
templates/configmap.yaml
------------------------
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  {{- $items := include "list.listNames" . | fromYaml }}
  NAMES: {{ $items.items | join "," | quote }}
```